# SQL get consecutive starting and end date with specific period

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a hotel_availablities table something like this.

| date | availability |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-15 | y |
| 2021-01-16 | y |
| 2021-01-17 | y |
| 2021-01-18 | n |
| 2021-01-19 | n |
| 2021-01-20 | y |
| 2021-01-21 | n |
| 2021-01-22 | y |
| 2021-01-23 | y |

I wanted to get the results of possible available date range values where period of stay is **2 days**.

| date range |
| --- |
| 2021-01-15 : 2021-01-16 |
| 2021-01-16 : 2021-01-17 |
| 2021-01-22 : 2021-01-23 |

If period of stays was **3 day**s I would get results as below

| date range |
| --- |
| 2021-01-15 : 2021-01-18 |

How can I achieve this result with sql?

Comment: what is your dbms? and how should be your output? just a table with one column or a table with 2 columns containing start and end?

Comment: My mysql version is 8.0.21

Comment: It could be in single or two column containing start and end date  @MohammadMirsafaei

Comment: I'd observe that this is a rather unusual way of storing availability

Answer (score 1):

This is a gaps and islands problem.  Assuming you are using MySQL 8+, we can use the difference in row numbers method here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY availability ORDER BY date) rn2
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT MIN(date) AS start_date, MAX(date) AS end_date, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM cte
WHERE availability = 'y'
GROUP BY rn1 - rn2
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;    -- but change to COUNT(*) >= 3, e.g. for three days in a row
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Note that my query does not give the exact output you expect, but maybe this would be enough for your requirement.  If you wanted to break out each island *larger* than 2 days in terms of pairs of 2 days at a time, you might have to also bring in a calendar table here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a row for each date, you can use a single window function -- and no aggregation.  That window function is a count of 'y" in the current row and next n - 1 days:

```
select date, date + interval <n - 1> day
from (select t.*,
             sum(availability = 'y') over (order by date
                                           rows between current row and <n - 1> following
                                          ) as num_y
      from t
     ) t
where num_y = <n>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Through below query you can achieve that. First I have numbered the rows with row_number()
user lead() to get next consecutive dates. In lead second parameter is determining how many consecutive dates will be considered.

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT date ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY date) rownumber
  FROM hotel_availablities  where availability='y'
  
),
t2 as (SELECT date StartDate ,lead(date ,1)over (partition by date_add(date ,INTERVAL -rownumber day)) EndDate
FROM t)
select concat(startdate,' - ',enddate)daterange from t2 where enddate is not null
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are welcome. It was a nice problem to work on. Thanks for the opportunity. Hope It solved your problem.